# WebGL2: what is up with max elements indices/vertices?

Tags: graphics, three.js, gpu, webgl, webgl2

I'm developing a web component using WebGL2 (and three.js) with
OES_element_index_uint enabled.  I'm drawing a geometry using indexed
vertices and I'm seeing the following anomaly -- look for the lines going
across the middle of the figure:

[image: anomalous 3d figure]

If I redraw the figure I get something slightly different even if I don't change
the inputs (I think).

I've made debug code to double check the buffers I'm passing in to the geometry
and I don't find any problem.  I also haven't noticed anything like this using the
same implementation with smaller data sets (yet).

I looked at this webgl2 report site https://alteredqualia.com/tools/webgl-features/
and I notice the lines:

```
                 Max elements vertices: 1048575
                  Max elements indices: 150000
```

Could this be the cause of the anomaly because my buffers are bigger than that?
Where are these numbers explained?

I'm working on a Mac Laptop with the GPU reported as

```
                     Unmasked renderer: AMD Radeon Pro 560X OpenGL Engine
                       Unmasked vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
```

Any clues as to what is going on or explanations about max elements indices/vertices would be much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you load the form a file? Wavefront (OBJ)? Start the indices at 0 or 1?

Comment: No,. I build the geometry myself using a program I wrote. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Any chance you could create a working demo through jsfiddle.net or codepen.io? I'm getting 2billion max vertices on my desktop, while you're getting 1million. It would be interesting to see if it displays properly on my machine.

Comment: @Marquizzo -- good idea -- I may do that just to confirm that that is the problem.  I have since determined that 'unrolling' the index to a non-indexed geometry fixes the issue, but adds overhead, of course.  I guess because I want to support even 3 year old mac laptops like mine, that's the way I'll be doing it for the time being.

Comment: I don't see a similar anomaly, but I came up with a codepen that gives me a black box (with no exception of console message) if the mesh is large enough: https://codepen.io/aaronwatters/pen/PopwMBJ

Answer (score 0):

I'm rendering in WebGL1.0 and I've found the 64k vertex limitation to be "a thing". I get features like those long triangles like that appearing from nowhere when I hit this "thing".

The way to resolve it is to split your model up into several models so that no sub-model has more than 64k vertices.

I haven't tested the boundary on this myself but by some reports, you should maybe consider 65000 to be the boundary of max vertices per model as you may experience some issues if you use 65535.

Answer (score 0):

To draw an object using `drawElements` WebGL2 allows you to define indices of data type `gl.UNSIGNED_INT`  up to 4294967296. You have to pass a `Uint32Array` array: `new Uint32Array(indices)` to your created and binded index buffer:

```
const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(
    gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    new Uint32Array(indices),
    gl.STATIC_DRAW
);
```

In `drawElements` pass `gl.UNSIGNED_UINT` as index type:

```
gl.drawElements(primitive, count, gl.UNSIGNED_UINT, offset);
```

With THREE.js in `setIndex` for your Buffer Geometry :

```
  bg = new THREE.BufferGeometry();    
  bg.setIndex( new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Uint32Array( indices ), 1 ) );
```